# One variable type two object on different conditions in android studio

Tags: java, android, class

I have two classes and I should create an object from them.

```
public someType person;

if (type.equals("student")){
    person = new Student();
}else{
    person = new Teacher();
}
```

I want to do it because I have two account in my application and their functions, abilities are sometimes different. If a student login to the application, something is different will be ran than Teacher.

What should I do ? What should someType be ?

Thanks for all helps...

Comment: `What should someType be` well, considering it can be either `Student` or `Teacher`, you either need to use some sort of base class/interface or perhaps some type of base object the langauge uses, perhaps Object

Comment: `someType` should be a type that both `Student` and `Teacher` implement/extend

Comment: @a_local_nobody can I access Student functions if I use Object class ? I tried but not worked.

Comment: @QBrute Unfortunatelly I can't extend as it extends View class for something. I tried to implement with an interface but I could not access Student or Teacher functions.

Comment: no, because it will no longer be a student or a teacher, it will be of type Object, so you would have to cast it or do some type checking, perhaps you're going to find a better answer by explaining what you want to achieve

Comment: @a_local_nobody I added more details to question.

Comment: well i see no need for the way you're trying to do this. when a user logs in, you can simply use a boolean value to determine `isTeacher`,  if it is false, well, then they are a student

Comment: @a_local_nobody but I can't take the object outside of the if statement. Maybe I could not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Before I can properly answer your question, I believe a few more things need to be clarified. Are "Student" and "Teacher" sub-types of a "Person" (or different name) class? I think this is the case, since I see that the person is `someType`, but want to make sure.

If so, take a look at the Factory design pattern. This may help you write clear code.

So, I would model something like this. Have a `Person` Abstract class (or interface)

```java
public interface Person {
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingElse();
}
```

Next, have the two other classes implement that interface:

```java
public class Student implements Person {
    public void doSomething() {
        // implementation
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class Teacher implements Person {
    public void doSomething() {
        // implementation
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Next, you can have a `PersonFactory` that returns the type of person needed.

This assumes that both `Teacher` and `Person` have common functionalities (even though different implementations).

Comment: Yes, they have common function but also different functions. I can't access the different fuctions with this way.